Performance impact of Java Streams in Matrix traversal
I have two versions of some code to diagonally traverse an MxN matrix. Apparently, even with the same (bad) traversal logic the version which uses Java Streams run 5x slower that the one which doesn't.
Constraints:

1 <= M, N  <= 10^4
1 <= M * N <= 10^4

Version 1: Using for loops:
public int[] findDiagonalOrder(int[][] mat) {
        int M = mat.length;
        int N = mat[0].length;

        int[] traversal = new int[M * N];
        int s = 0;
        for(int sum=0; sum < M+N; sum++) {
            for(int k=0; k<=sum; k++) {
                int row = (sum%2 == 0) ? sum - k : k;
                if (row < M && (sum-row < N))
                    traversal[s++] = mat[row][sum-row];
            }
        }
        return traversal;
}

Version 2: Using Java Streams:
    public int[] findDiagonalOrder(int[][] matrix) {
        int M = matrix.length;
        int N = matrix[0].length;

        return IntStream.range(0, M+N)
                .flatMap(sum -> IntStream.rangeClosed(0, sum)
                        .filter(i -> {
                            int row = (sum%2 == 0) ? (sum-i) : i;
                            return row < M && (sum - row) < N;
                        })
                        .map(i -> (sum%2 == 0) ? matrix[sum-i][i] : matrix[i][sum-i]))
                .toArray();
    }

Version #1 runs in approximately 353 msec, while Version #2 runs in 1500 msec. I wanted to understand, what is causing this degradation in performance? I'm not even using Boxing/Unboxing which may have had an impact.
PS: I understand there is a better way for matrix traversal in O(M*N), but my question is about Streams.

Streams have overhead. Throw a RuntimeException from a peek() method and you will see you are several method calls deep: as opposed to none in your version #1 case.

Streams have massive overhead, and whenever you can avoid and have to look after performance, avoid. There are good reasons to rely on streams, for eg processing large amount of constant data, or go for parallelism (also only resonable with thousands of data items), but all in all, just doing small datasets, streams are only convenient but nothing at all performant.

Also, as you can see, you're doing sum%2 == 0 twice. Maybe the compiler can work that out to a certain degree, you'd have to take a deeper look into the Bytecode for that, but in the end in matrix computation it all burns down to minimizing operations and get the cache working at its best.

@Slevin - You would need to look at the native code.  The JIT compiler does all of the heavy lifting in optimizing the code.

@StephenC So the Bytecode isn't telling the truth about the final optimization? I thought such simple things like detecting an operation twice would be done during compilation to Bytecode, while optimization for the processor of course can only be done by the JIT compiler. Thanks. Anyhow, since the questioner is trying to sqeeze performance, it should be mentioned that in his case having Java primitives lined up correctly in the array for proper cacheline fetching is mandatory, not only in C but also in Java. (You can't do that kind of preparation in scripting languages like JS or Python)

"So the Bytecode isn't telling the truth about the final optimization?" - Correct!!

@Slevin there’s one thing you could learn when looking at the bytecode. It’s that in this specific situation, it’s impossible to eliminate the redundancy of the two sum%2 in the bytecode. The reason is that the two references to sum will by different variables on the bytecode level (as these are two occurrences of capturing the same value but in different lambda expressions).


I wanted to understand, what is causing this degradation in performance?

The short answer is probably stream overheads.
Performance is not the primary goal of Java streams.  In current versions of Java, the compilers are not (yet) able to transform stream-based code into native code that performs as well as classic loops.  In the future this may change.  However, significant R&D effort would need to make that happen, and (AFAIK) this is not currently a priority for the Java team.
So the simplistic "corollary" is that if performance1 is the most important requirement for a given code fragment2, you shouldn't be using streams in the solution.

I'm not even using Boxing/Unboxing which may have had an impact.

Not explicitly.  But it could be happening under the covers.  The only way to be absolutely sure would be to analyze all of the native code emitted by the JIT compiler3.  Profiling your benchmark may also give you the answer ... if the answer is that there >is< boxing / unboxing behind the scenes.
Finally, since you haven't shown us your complete benchmark, it is quite possible that your results (353 msec versus 1500 msec) are not representative of how the corresponding code would perform in a production context.  Read How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java? and the various sources that the answers cite.

1 - Actual performance right now, rather than potential performance in the future.
2 - However this is typically NOT the case.  Even in a performance critical application, most of the lines of code for that application don't have significant impact on overall performance.
3 - Bytecodes do not give a reliable indication of code performance.  Optimization is done by the JIT compiler not the bytecode compiler.  There could potentially be instructions to do boxing and unboxing in the bytecodes that are completely optimized away in the native code.
